# In Terraform, how do I repeat a dynamic block by an integer count?

Tags: for-loop, terraform

I need to add [multiple `scratch_disk` clauses](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#scratch_disk) to a resource for a Google Cloud VM.

I can use the following...

```
resource ... {
  dynamic "scratch_disk" {
    for_each = var.scratch_disk_count
    content {
      interface = "SCSI"
    }
  }
}
```

but then `var.scratch_disk_count` needs to be `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` which looks a bit silly.

I tried replacing `for_each` with `count = 4` but terraform said it didn't expect `count` there.

Is there a function to produce `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` from `4`, or just some generally better way?

This is a simple characterisation of the problem - I understand I could have the list be [ "SCSI", "SCSI", "NVME" ] or similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use the `range` function for this:

```
resource ... {
  dynamic "scratch_disk" {
    for_each = range(var.scratch_disk_count)
    content {
      interface = "SCSI"
    }
  }
}
```

In your example above where the value of `var.scratch_disk_count` is `4`, then the return of the `range` function will be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, and will produce the desired behavior. Note that it is also common to use the `range` function in dynamic blocks in this manner.